# heroku can't find pip when I push app to it

Tags: python, django, heroku

When I try to push my django app to heroku it fails right at the beginning:

```
  remote: -----> Python app detected
  remote: -----> Installing python-3.5.1
  remote: -----> Installing pip
  remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
  remote:        /app/tmp/buildpacks/779a8bbfbbe7e1b715476c0b23fc63a2103b3e4131eda558669aba8fb5e6e05682419376144189b29beb5dee6d7626b4d3385edb0954bffea6c67d8cf622fd51/
  bin/steps/pip-install: line 5: /app/.heroku/python/bin/pip:
  No such file or directory
  remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
  remote:
```

I apparently do something wrong, but I did the same thing many times before. What's wrong?

Comment: The path to pip could be wrong it's hard to tell without more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this exact same problem yesterday and it was really frustrating as I had deployed to Django before under the exact same settings with no problem.

In your runtime.txt file change it from:

```
python-3.5.1
```

to

```
python-3.6.1
```

Why changing the Python version on Heroku matters beats me but it worked like a charm.